# What is the right way to change primary keys to a new property in Realm?

Tags: javascript, realm, realm-migration

I added a new property to my schema.  That property is the new primary key.  (In real life this primary key correpsonds to a composite key of the record's key and a key for the user.)

My code works.  However it feels complex (having to convert the results to an array and then cloning them):

```
function migrationThatWorks(oldRealm, newRealm) {
    let results = readRecords(newRealm); 
    let cloned = clone(_.values(results));
    newRealm.delete(results);
    cloned.forEach(r => r.Key = 'test' + r.Id);
    cloned.forEach(r => newRealm.create(mySchema, r, true));

    readRecords(newRealm);
}
function clone(c) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Ideally I'd want something like:

```
realm.updateAll(mySchema, r => r.Key = 'test' + r.Id);
```

Here's a full working example:

```
var Realm = require('realm');
var _ = require('lodash');

var mySchema = 'MySchema';

v1();
v2();

function v1() {
    var schema1 = {
        name: mySchema,
        primaryKey: 'Id',
        properties: {
            Id: 'int',
        }
    };
    var realm1 = new Realm({
        schema: [
            schema1
        ],    
        schemaVersion: 1
    });

    createRecord(realm1, 1);
    createRecord(realm1, 2);
    readRecords(realm1);
    realm1.close();
}

function v2() {
    var schema2 = {
        name: mySchema,
        primaryKey: 'Key',
        properties: {
            Id: 'int',
            Key: 'string',
        }
    };
    let realm2 = new Realm({
        schema: [
            schema2
        ],    
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migration: migrationThatWorks,
    });
}

function migrationThatWorks(oldRealm, newRealm) {
    let results = newRealm.objects(mySchema); 
    let cloned = clone(_.values(results));
    newRealm.delete(results);
    cloned.forEach(r => r.Key = 'test' + r.Id);
    cloned.forEach(r => newRealm.create(mySchema, r, true));

    readRecords(newRealm);
}

function clone(c) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
}

function readRecords(realm) {
    var result = realm.objects(mySchema);
    console.log(result);
    if (_.values(result).length !== 2) {
        throw 'not expecting this';
    }
    return result;
}

function createRecord(realm, id) {
    realm.write(() => {
        realm.create(mySchema, {
            Id: id,
        }, true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using sync, react native, or node?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I inherited this project and am not familiar with the tools.  I *believe* it's react native.  Although the code above was ran using `node index`

Comment: ....like, is this server-side code, or is this supposedly running on iOS/android devices? :P also is there a "Realm Object Server" and `SyncConfiguration` involved in the process, or no such thing?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce definitely android. Searching for the string `SyncConfiguration` returned nothing. Not sure about Realm Object Server.  I think the only realm thing we do is `new Realm` and then make calls to that like `objects` and `write`.

Comment: In that case all I found was https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#performing-a-migration which is tricky in the sense that it uses "automatic schema mode" and I'm not entirely sure how that works, other than that you seem to receive both previous and new version of Realm (with given schema) and you can access the data from one and map it over to the other. Someone who's worked with Realm-Swift would know better because it follows the same strategy but with Javascript. I'm surprised you can actually make a new primary key though with this setup :O